# How to gather build result of a build series in hudson?

Tags: hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins

I have 1 upstream job and 2 parallel downstream jobs. When the upstream job succeeds, 2 downstream jobs will be triggered.
Currently, I send mail notice for every jobs separately. Not the receivers are complaining for to many mails.

I need to find out a way to gather the build result of those 3 jobs together and send 1 mail notice.

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameterized trigger plugin as a build step (not as a post-build action).  I believe it can wait for downstream projects to finish, examine their status, and set the current project's status accordingly.